Prevent standard users from deleting of folders and files within
I have 2 accounts. One admin and a standard account. Logging in with the Admin account, within the C drive/Program Files, I have followed the steps Prevent deletion of folders to prevent the deletion of the folders and sub folders and files by giving deny permission. This works fine.
Problem is, when I login as the standard user and when I copy and move these folders to the Documents, I can delete these folders and also the Documents folder. How I prevent the deletion.
The reason why I am copying and moving is, I want to restrict the usage of C Drive for the standard user. Also When I right click on the Documents and follow the steps in the link to give deny permissions, it says something like cannot enumerate the folder, C:/Documents/My Music. Please help.
(Also people suggest me to use Kiosk mode. But within the kiosk mode I don't know how I can only have access to Desktop, Downloads and Documents to the user.)
